# dynamically function call from String template

Tags: java, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

Is it possible to call a function of Java class through  dynamically generated function from StringTemplate ?

for instance, following is a Java class with three functions

```
public class RegionManager {

    public static List<String> getCenter(){
       return somelist; 
    }   

    public static List<String> getFloor(){
         return somelist;   
    }

    public static List<String> getRoom(){
         return somelist;   
    }   

}
```

Now, my String template file contains  `$CS.name$` .. the value of could be "Room", "Floor", "Center".

based on the `$CS.name$` value, I want to call function ( could be `getRoom(), getFloor(), getCenter()` ) . Please note that When I write String template file, I do not know , which function is going to be called.

Comment: May I know -- why do you give -ve to this question ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49125672/2158970

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call static functions.  You can only call getters on objects.

Answer (score 2):

As it was already mentioned, you can't call static functions in your template. However, there is another interesting mechanism, which can help you out with your requirement.

[StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) library has a mechanism of custom [Renderers](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/renderers.md).

You can build a renderer, which will call your static method, based on the input and / or potentially format e.g.

`<your_item; format="your_format">`

I hope that will help to solve your problem. It helped me a lot in different templates.

Comment: Both links are broken/require signup.