# Calling Java function with arguments from StringTemplate?

Tags: java, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

StringTemplate allows programmers to fetch data through getters(a function with no arguments).

I would like to know that Is it possible to call Java function with arguments from String Template?

Comment: Not really. That would allow "executing code" and violating separations. However, the attribute format support -- e.g. `format="1,2,3,4"` could be abused...

Comment: It's also possible to artificially simulate function-like behaviour by creating a map and putting into it some values and expected results. Then you can use such a map like a function in the template:
<object.map.("value")>

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround by abusing dictionaries. Here is an example of implementing "function" for limiting item count in a List ([issue on github](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/issues/197)).

In your code add dictionary:

`group.defineDictionary("max", new MaxListItemsLimiter());`

Usage (in this example first item in array is max. items count):

`<max.(["50",myObject.items]):{msg|<msg.something>}>`

```
final class MaxListItemsLimiter extends AbstractMap<String, Object> {

    @Override
    public Object get(Object key) {
        List items = (List) key;
        if (!items.isEmpty()) {
            //First item is max. count
            Integer limit = NumberUtils.toInt(items.get(0).toString(), -1); //use Integer.parseInt
            if (limit != -1) {
                return items.subList(1, Math.min(items.size(), limit + 1));
            } else {
                throw new AssertionError("First parameter in max must be number");
            }
        } else {
            return super.get(key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entrySet() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        if (key instanceof List) {
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new AssertionError("You can use max only on Lists.");
        }
    }
}
```